# Error 13 en highcharts

Tags: php, javascript, sql, highcharts

Tengo un chart creado cogiendo dato de una consulta sql, en este caso el dato que está recibiendo es [82,5] y no funciona, se queda en blanco y no se porque, ademas, y esto sí que no se como hacerlo, como título de cada "porción" de la tarta, quiero poner el valor resultado, aquí os adjunto el código.

El resultado de la consulta es:

```
Resultado | num
---------------------
correcto  | 82
error     | 5
```

Y el codigo:

```php
<?php
$chart1=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT Resultado, COUNT(*) AS `num` FROM informes GROUP BY Resultado");
while($chart01=mysqli_fetch_array($chart1)){
    $data[]= $chart01['num'];
}
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart:{
            renderTo: 'resultados',
            type: 'pie'
        },
        title: {
            text: 'Resultados',
            x: -20 //center
        },
        series:[{
            data:[<?php echo join($data,',')?>],
            pointStart: 0
        }]
    });
</script>
<div id="resultados">
</div>
```

Comment: En _series_ no estás proporcionando un formato adecuado, adapta para enviar como aparecen en [la demo](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/pie-legend). Clic en _View options_